# Should I use Middleware or write a decorator for this?

Tags: django

I have a situation where a user will be asked to enter their postal code, once they do then they are redirected to the site with content relevant to the postal code they've entered in. There will be categories etc. In a nutshell, the user will see content only relevant to their area.

**PLAN** --
I want to store their postal code in a cookie and re-use it every time they come back to the site, of course if there is no postal code they should be directed to enter it in a form. The form will be presented before any other content will be.

My questions are should I use a decorator for this and decorate the views with a custom decorator? Or should write middleware? if I write a custom middleware for this should I use process_request process_view, it seems to me process_request gets called on EVERY request, this may pose a problem.

Thanks!

JeffC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main question here is how often will you need to use the ZIP code from the cookie. Will it affect the whole site? Or only one part of it?

If the "ZIP-oriented" content will be used only in one part (one or more, but not the whole application), then go for the decorator. It should check for the cookie and if it's not present - redirect to the ZIP selection form. If it's present - continue processing the view in which you will be able to access the ZIP code and use it accordingly.

If the ZIP code is really going to affect the majority of your service and you don't want to decorate every single view - you can go for the middleware. But you are right - it will be called on every request, so be sure it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: it's only going to reflect part of the site, it's a large content section where it only seems natural to allow the user to see the content related to their area.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid repetition, you'll need to write a middleware. If it's on EVERY page as you say, and the ZIP code is a prerequisite for using the site, then having a middleware call `process_request` on every request isn't necessarily a bad thing.

On the other hand, is this necessary? Couldn't your URLs just read like: `/blah/12345/videos/`? Then instead of having to rely on a cookie for a bookmark, your users can just remmber that page. That would negate your having to write a view, as well.

Comment: Treating the zipcode as a URL parameter is very clean solution.

Comment: are you suggesting that instead of this whole middleware/decorator stuff that I just write a view that prompts the form first and then passes the zipcode to the url for every other view?

Comment: I don't mind avoiding the whole decorator/middleware stuff, I just want to be sure that the user see's the content specific to his/her area, a parameter would be ok, I just figured it would be more DRY to write a dec or middleware to handle this request before processing content

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, the author wants to select appropriate content for display SERVER-side. Ask once, then remember the choice on the server for future usage. Asking the users to bookmark specific URL, isn't really a solution in this case.

Comment: The main advantage of putting the zipcode right in the url is that the user can bookmark the page and be able to see the same content as before. Imagine the confusion if you used cookies and it got cleared, and the user went back to a bookmark and there is a completely different page.

Comment: @JeffC: http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html might help here. The basic idea is that your visitors can expect a standard experience from your site. Having content constantly changing on the page is going to make it harder for Google to index as well, leading to lower ranking pages.

@Jakub Gocławski: I'm not asking the users to bookmark it, it's just a side effect of good URL design, and using the right tools. Would you try and get a screw in with a hammer? Possible, but suboptimal.